# How to find adjusted mean in linear regression in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am trying to build a multiple linear regression model:

```
lm1 <- lm(outcome ~ sex + age + education + cohort, data=data.in)
```

Among the independent variables, sex, education, and cohort are all categorical variables, so should I add factor() for these variables in the model?
I also need to get the adjusted(estimated) mean for the outcome for males and for females separately, so I created two datasets separated by sex:

```
data.in.m <- data.in %>% fitler(sex==1)
data.in.f <- data.in %>% fitler(sex==2)
```

Then I tried to use

```
mean(fitted(lm1,data.in.m))
```

or

```
mean(predict(lm1,data.in.m))
```

to get the adjusted mean outcomes in males (from the original dataset).

I am not sure if I should use fitted() or predict() since the two functions give two different values here.

Comment: _"should I add factor() for these variables?"_ Only if they are currently numeric. If they already are characters or factors then you don't need to (but it doesn't hurt either). To get separate estimates for males and females, use the `emmeans` package to estimate marginal means. Don't fit separate models. It will look something like `emmeans(lm1, ~ sex)`

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful! Just want to check what do you mean by 'marginal means'? I'm also wondering if it's possible to calculate the standard deviation with this package?

Comment: Marginal means are the means after averaging over other effects in the model (i.e. probably what you mean when you say adjusted means). `emmeans` has lots of very nice vignettes and documentation. Start e.g. by reading [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/basics.html).

Comment: Sounds clear to me. Thank you!